# Is it possible to access variables from another class in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

High level: I have a class A, which has a variable defined as "let _somevar".
I'm looking for ways to assign value to this variable from another class, B.

The details are a bit more involved:
Class A contains an initialization method to lazy load some module, and it has a variable "_somevar" which holds the module which is lazy loaded. Class A also has some **public methods** which checks whether this variable is null or not and executes accordingly.

Now Class B provides an initialization function to synchronously/directly (not lazy-load-ly) load the module. The problem is the **public methods** from Class A now wouldn't run because "_somevar" is not set. So I'm trying to set it from Class B so that the public methods in Class A can still be used.

I understand there's a lot of refactoring that can be done to these classes. but I don't own the codebase and I'm trying to make minimal code changes here to make it work.

I'd love to hear your suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to access *variables* in another class.

You *can* access public members, such as properties and methods.

If you extend a class, the subclass can access protected members.

Here are some solutions, two of them promote the variable to be a property. The other doesn't.

## Constructor

If `ClassA` depends on the initialization of `somevar` it can make the dependency explicit by requiring the dependency in its constructor. That way, you can't call a method that uses the dependency before the dependency is supplied.

```
class Example {
    constructor(private somevar: SomeVar) {
    }


    myMethod() {
        this._somevar.doSomething();
    }
}
```

## Set Dependency

If you are doing a light-tough change to fix your issue, you could add a method that accepts the dependency:

```
setDependency(somevar: SomeVar) {
    this.somevar = somevar;
}
```

You can then call this before using the method that is currently failing. However, this is a form of temporal coupling. `setDependency` needs to be called before `myMethod` is called.

## Pass to Method

The method that fails when the dependency isn't initialized could be changed to require the dependency...

For example, this:

```
myMethod() {
    this._somevar.doSomething();
}
```

Becomes this:

```
myMethod(somevar: SomeVar) {
    somevar.doSomething();
}
```